# R: Size of a file. What is the difference between file.info()$size and object.size()?

Tags: r, file-handling

I want to know the size of a file in *R*. Should i use 
 **file.info(pathtodata)$size** or **object.size(pathtodata)** ? 
 *(or a other solution?)* 
And what is the difference between them?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking about the size of the file as stored on the hard disk or the size it takes when loaded into R?

Comment: I need the size as stored on the hard disk. Is this the difference?

Comment: As far as I'm aware - yes that's the difference here.  Note that if you're passing the path to object.size as a string then what it's telling you is how much memory that the string takes up in R.

Comment: `object.size("path/to/data")` is the size of the string "path/to/data" (120 bytes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general `object.size()` should be larger than a file's size on disk because R objects will have metadata associated with them that occupies additional memory - see [Hadley's article here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html). On top of this, different object classes will have different memory footprints:

```
write.csv(
  matrix(1:1000),
  file="~/tmp/foo.csv",
  row.names=FALSE)
##
df <- read.csv(
  "~/tmp/foo.csv",
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
mat <- as.matrix(df)
##
R> file.info("~/tmp/foo.csv")$size
#[1] 3898
R> object.size(df)
#4672 bytes
R> object.size(mat)
#4464 bytes
R> file.info("~/tmp/foo.csv")$size
#[1] 3898
R> system("stat ~/tmp/foo.csv")
#  File: ‘/home/nr07/tmp/foo.csv’
#  Size: 3898       Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
```

---

In the above example, the `data.frame` occupies more memory than the `matrix`, even though they were constructed from the same underlying data; and both of these occupy more space than the file itself does on disk.